# How to write data from code to SQLite in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, sqlite, dart

I'm developing a simple app that displays a list of items as a to-do app, but I don't want the user to write the instances to record the to-dos, but instead create those instances myself from code.

I want to make inserts or instances from code, like title, description, etc... so that they are saved locally, I don't want users to create the to-do instances themselves, I just want to create inserts one by one.

this is my code to add instances to SQLite:

```
class _AddScreenState extends State<AddScreen> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  String title = "";
  String description = "";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Add todo'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              TextFormField(
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                    return 'Please enter some text';
                  }
                  return null;
                },
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'title',
                ),
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    title = value;
                  });
                },
              ),
              TextFormField(
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                    return 'Please enter some text';
                  }
                  return null;
                },
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Description',
                ),
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    description = value;
                  });
                },
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                    await DatabaseHandler()
                        .inserttodo(todo(
                            title: title,
                            description: description,
                            id: Random().nextInt(50)))
                        .whenComplete(() => Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) => ListScreen()),
                            ));
                  } else {
                    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                      SnackBar(content: Text('Processing Data')),
                    );
                  }
                },
                child: const Text(
                  'Add',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

this is my databaseHandler class

```
class DatabaseHandler {
  Future<Database> initializeDB() async {
    String path = await getDatabasesPath();
    return openDatabase(
      join(path, 'tododatabase.db'),
      onCreate: (database, version) async {
        await database.execute(
          'CREATE TABLE todos(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, title TEXT, description TEXT)',
        );
      },
      version: 1,
    );
  }

  Future<void> inserttodo(todo todo) async {
    final db = await initializeDB();
    await db.insert(
      'todos',
      todo.toMap(),
      conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace,
    );
  }

  Future<List<todo>> todos() async {
    final db = await initializeDB();
    final List<Map<String, dynamic>> queryResult = await db.query('todos');
    return queryResult.map((e) => todo.fromMap(e)).toList();
  }

  Future<void> deletetodo(int id) async {
    final db = await initializeDB();
    await db.delete(
      'todos',
      where: 'id = ?',
      whereArgs: [id],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not create them inside `onCreate`?

Comment: it sounds fine, but i have not idea how to make that

Comment: may be is only make multiples "inserts" of objects inside a ListView ListTile

Answer (score 1):

Run a query for each row before creation.

```
onCreate: (database, version) async {
        await database.execute(
          'CREATE TABLE todos(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, title TEXT, description TEXT)',
        );
        await database.execute(
          'INSERT INTO todos(id, title, description)
           VALUES (value1,value2 ,...),
                 (value1,value2 ,...),
                 (value1,value2 ,...);'
        );
      },
```

Comment: thanks, can i make multiple inserts, inside same method?, like:
'INSERT INTO todos(id, title, description) VALUES(1, "first", "description")',
'INSERT INTO todos(id, title, description) VALUES(1, "second", "description")',
'INSERT INTO todos(id, title, description) VALUES(1, "third", "description")',
...

Comment: @MrK Updated the answer to insert multiple values in the same query.

Comment: Thanks. is that id automatic? or do I have to write one by one in each value

Comment: You can use sqlite's autoincrement on table creation https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-autoincrement/

Comment: i've implemented that code, but i can not see that values in the list screen, thats not work for me, sorry